# C# CodeDOM: Adding Enum members at runtime

Tags: c#, codedom

What I'm trying to do is add a "NoneOfTheBelow" choice to all enums parsed from an XSD file.
I'm expanding on code from the [Xsd2Code tool](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/).

When I generate output using the code below, the enum does not contain the new member I added.
Can anyone help?

```
var ns = new CodeNamespace();

/* ... Initialize ns from XSD ... */

// Create a dummy array for iteration, because a collection cannot be modified when it is being iterated over.
CodeTypeDeclarationCollection types = new CodeTypeDeclarationCollection();
foreach (CodeTypeDeclaration t0 in ns.Types)
{
   types.Add(new CodeTypeDeclaration(t0.Name));
}

// Scan for enum types and add desired markup to the members.
int typeIndex = 0;
foreach (CodeTypeDeclaration t0 in types)
{
   CodeTypeDeclaration t = ns.Types[typeIndex];

   // Add an element for blank entry to the enum.
   CodeTypeMember noneOfTheBelow = new CodeTypeMember();
   noneOfTheBelow.Name = "NoneOfTheBelow";
   noneOfTheBelow.Comments.Add(new CodeCommentStatement( "<summary>None of the below.</summary>"));
   noneOfTheBelow.CustomAttributes.Add(new CodeAttributeDeclaration("XmlEnum", new CodeAttributeArgument(new CodePrimitiveExpression("Test"))));
   noneOfTheBelow.CustomAttributes.Add(new CodeAttributeDeclaration("Description", new CodeAttributeArgument(new CodePrimitiveExpression("Test"))));
   t.Members.Insert(0, noneOfTheBelow);
}
```

Comment: Your second loop doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For enumerations, you need to add CodeMemberField instances, not CodeTypeMember, so something like:

```
CodeMemberField noneOfTheBelow = new CodeMemberField();
noneOfTheBelow.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Static;
noneOfTheBelow.Name = "NoneOfTheBelow";
t.Members.Insert(0, noneOfTheBelow);
```

Comment: I'm curious, do Public and Static attributes have any effect on the enum member?  I seem to get the same output without that line setting the attributes.

Comment: @dythim - Hmm... I've copied a piece of code from my own sources, but they maybe useless :-) It depends also on the CodeDom provider (c#, VB.Net, etc.)